Insulating water pipe be under bathroom floor
I have an old building from 1880. The first floor bathroom is an addition on the side of the building. The water pipe connected to the main comes up through the dirt, through the floor and attaches to the sink. The downstairs is heated by a propane renai heater in the other room so the bathroom isn’t as warm.
After removing part of the floor, I found a mess of old insulation lying directly on the dirt. I also found a plastic bag full of old horse hair that was wrapped around the pipes. After removing all of this insulation, old heat tape and the plastic bag I’m ready to re insulate the pipe with a better method this time around.
Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Where are you (climate, product availability etc. all vary)? Do you have pests that will chew on plastic-based insulation?

Is the area under your bathroom open to your basement/down stairs area?

I'm not a fan of heat tape on pipes in inaccessible areas.

And like Chris asked, what part of the country are you in?  Recommendations for a home in the Mid Atlantic would be different than for one in northern Minnesota.
